# browsersync only reloads 'root' index.html

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am working on a website build tool (https://github.com/bmargogne/website-builder.git). **BrowserSync works perfectly while being on the root index.html, but it does not reload anywhere else...**

Here is the (simplified) way of how I did... Let's say I have :

```
src/index.html
src/_header.html
src/page/index2.Html
```

One task **builds HTML pages** by including html partials (their names start with '_')

```
gulp.task('pagesHtml', () => {
    const SRC = 'src/**/*.html';
    const EXCLUDE = '!src/**/_*.html';
    return gulp.src( [SRC, EXCLUDE], { ignoreInitial: false } )
        pipe(   fileinclude({ prefix: '@@', basepath: co.src }))
        .pipe(  gulp.dest( 'www/' ));
});
```

One task **start browser Sync** server

```
gulp.task('serveLocal', () => {
    return browserSync.init({
        server:{ baseDir : 'www' },
        port: 3000,         
        open: true
    }); 
});
```

One task is called to **reload browserSync** (separated, as it is called by other 'watchers tasks' from my project)

```
gulp.task('liveReload', ()) => {
    browserSync.reload();
});
```

And one task **watch all HTML** (including partials) and should rebuild the whole page, then reload.

```
gulp.task('watch-pagesHtml', () => {
    const SRC = 'src/**/*.html';        
    return watch( SRC, () => {
        runSequence('pagesHtml', 'liveReload');
    });
    return;
});
```

I **start** these tasks by starting runSequence like this :

```
gulp.task('default', () => {
    runSequence('pagesHtml', 'watch-pagesHtml');
});
```

When I work on `index` or `_header` : No problems at all! The changes are applied, built, and the browse reloads.

However, when I work on `pages/index2`, the changes are applied and built, but the browser does not reload. (though a F5 works and shows the change applied )

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Browsersync works by injecting an asynchronous script tag in the body, start your project and inspect the body tag. (With browser developer tool).

If you can't fine something like:
`<script async>...</script>` (and browsersync stuffs), there is the problem.

I read your code, and I notice that you write the `<body>` (open tag) in header file, and `</body>` (close tag)in other footer file, and it is confusing but I did not find the body tag in the other html files when I think that was necessary.

The browser "try" to fix errors in the html, auto completing tags from the original html file for example.

I have two possible answers to your problem.

1) The browser autocomplete the  tag in the header file, an also autocomplete the  tag in the footer file, so browsersync have problems to inject de asynchronous script tag that is necessary to reload the page because there are two bodies. (if this is possible)

2) The browser do not find the body tag in the html, so the browser create it after, but browsersync inject the script in your html file, not in the browser.

Make sure that the body tag is generated by your own code and not by the browser.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this analysis!. I will investigate where you suggest and tell you if I can solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but if someone still looking for an answer, you can do something like that:

```
var browserSync = require("browser-sync");

browserSync({
    proxy: "wordpress.dev",
    snippetOptions: {
        ignorePaths: "wp-admin/**"
    }
});
```